# Using NLog in Azure Functions

Tags: c#, azure-functions, nlog

I have an Azure functions which refers the custom dll which we have written to access the graph api calls. In the dll, we also have a NLog logger facility which helps to log the details.

Some thing like we have a NLog nuget package referred and we have a ILoggingService and LoggingService which implements the same and inside the LoggingService we have written like:

```
Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

Now I want my Azure function to use this logger and log the details that we are doing it in the dll as well while running the Azure function.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to redirect the NLog output from the custom dll into the Azure-function-console.

Then I guess you can do one of 2 things:

- Use the [MicrosoftILogger Target](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/MicrosoftILogger-Target) to redirect the NLog output to ILogger for the Azure-function.
- Configure NLog to write to the [Console target](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Console-target) and see if the Azure-function will automatically capture this output.

Both cases probably requires you to setup NLog Configuration using the [Config-API](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-API).

See also: [NLog cloud logging with Azure function](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/NLog-cloud-logging-with-Azure-function-or-AWS-lambda)

Answer (score 1):

You can register an `ILoggerProvider` in the DI system, then use `ILogger` from your function.

Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#logging-services

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you please eloborate a little more.. I have a function class Function and it has various Function methods... This Function class refers a dll for doing some common operation. If i use log.error() in the dll, i want the same to reflect in the function console.